# nginx connection tracking/activity when being used as a proxy

Tags: nginx, http-proxy

Using Nginx as a proxy for another HTTP application server. Is there a way to know for every 10 minutes how many connections are being dropped from ngnix to backend and also from front end to ngnix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Nginx Stub status](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule) module is your answer

[wtop](http://code.google.com/p/wtop/) might also come in handy.